# Problem setting [Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol in dockerfile for windows container

Tags: docker, docker-for-windows

I am trying to create a windows docker image on Windows Server 2016. I am having problems installing some packages due to the following error:

```
Exception calling "DownloadFile" with "2" argument(s): "The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel."
```

With some research, I found this is typically due to needing to set the [Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol parameter to Tls12. When I try setting this on my local machine and then downloading the packages, it works fine. However, when I try to do this through the dockerfile, it doesn't seem to work and the error remains the same. Am I doing something wrong here?

Dockerfile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:ltsc2016

RUN powershell [Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol -bor [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12

ADD https://chocolatey.org/installchocolatey.cmd .
RUN powershell \      
        [Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol -bor [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12; \  
        .\installchocolatey.cmd; \
        choco install --yes ghostscript --version=9.24 ;\
        choco install --yes imagemagick --version=7.0.10.14 ;
```

Comment: I don't suppose you ever found a solution to this?